# Having problems with creating a regex to filter paths

Tags: regex

I have paths that looks like this.

```
C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED\\160

C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\004\\133

C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\019-Feather-hydrolizer-other\\184
```

I am trying to create two Regex's.

If we use this path as an example:

```
C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED\\160
```

I want the first one to select `005`.
And the second regex to select `160`.

So basically the first regex should select the first number "`005`" after 4 `'\\'` and the second regex should select the number "160" after `'\\'` has shown up 5 times.

I only had luck on creating the regex for the last one `r'(.{3})\s*$`

But this is not bulletproof because it just takes the last 3 chars, and sometimes there is text after the last numbers after the `'\\'` has shown up four times. for example like this

```
C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED\\160-randomMachine
```

And in a case like this it should not select the last three chars, but instead choose '160'

I hope that somebody is able to help me out with this, it would help a lot :)

Comment: Maybe you could try [`^(?:[^\\]+\\){5}(\d+)[^\\]*\\(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/7igfos/1/) and use the two capture groups? What programming language are you using for this?

Comment: I tried to type that into Regexr.com using this "C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED\\160-RandomMachine"

But it does not seem to work unfortunately
https://regexr.com/6007v

@JvdV

Comment: Would `/(\d\d\d).*(\d\d\d)/` not be sufficient? I know it does not look at the `\\` in the path, so it doesn't match your description; that why it is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @ChristianAabyHøgh, do you see the difference in the sample you have here and in regexr? A double forwards slash =). Check the link I provided.

Comment: @JvdV Oh yes i see that thank you!, but i need i wold prefer to have to seperate regex's :D

Comment: A 1st `^(?:[^\\]+\\){5}(\d+)` and a 2nd `^(?:[^\\]+\\){6}(\d+)` then?

Comment: @JvdV Can you make two that selects C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED this from this path?

And one that selects C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\005-Coil-PED\\160-RandomMachine everything to here?

Comment: @JvdV the two regex's does not work in my python code

Comment: @JvdV The one you make sorts on path which is sperated by one "\" instead of two "\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first regex, you want:

`^(?:[^\\]+\\\\){5}(\d+).*$`

and for your second:

`^(?:[^\\]+\\\\){6}(\d+).*$`

if the paths truly include double-backslashes. If they are in fact single backslashes, the regex's should be `^(?:[^\\]+\\){5}(\d+).*$` and `^(?:[^\\]+\\){6}(\d+).*$`.